# What is the difference between Crypto and CryptoJS AES encryption? The results are different. (javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

The encryption results of the two libraries are different.
Can someone give me some advice?

```
//Crypto
const enCrypt = (plainText, key, iv) => {
    plainText = Buffer.from(plainText);
    let cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv("AES-128-CBC", key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, "", "");
    return Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]).toString("base64");
}

//Crypto-js
const encryptAES = (pText, init_key, init_iv) => {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(init_key);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(init_iv);
    
    const cipherData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pText, key, {
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    });
    return cipherData.ciphertext;
  }
```

//crypto-js result
ba0a16dc341853969069249a74649a865403d8887816479f3b4d907eb6f827d96364a6960009a548edae9997037cc5718e8a3655bd7181d017983cba8d8b6e798905a7bd90741569f72bfc8677e8f3e97c0bfeafef1a22aa1c3e3e0711a53cdb54f6ec088b54ed77d08914f33f86f4fdd7dd8afd95894b64d33ff5f50c226e179e35b8a5018615624b992ef6b2b8ab9a8fa08bb6052445b5baa27737fac0896930e260f3c26d129b0bfa66bc381d3e0859f0bf37713af7541ff25651119894ff

//crypto result
ugoW3DQYU5aQaSSadGSahlQD2Ih4FkefO02Qfrb4J9ljZKaWAAmlSO2umZcDfMVxjoo2Vb1xgdAXmDy6jYtueYkFp72QdBVp9yv8hnfo8+l8C/6v7xoiqhw+PgcRpTzbVPbsCItU7XfQiRTzP4b0/dfdiv2ViUtk0z/19QwibheeNbilAYYVYkuZLvayuKuaj6CLtgUkRbW6onc3+sCJaTDiYPPCbRKbC/pmvDgdPghZ8L83cTr3VB/yVlERmJT/

Comment: crypto-js looks like a string of hexadecimal - crypto looks like base64 - it's an identical result in a different "encoding" - hint: `.toString("base64")` is why you get base64 for crypto ... try `.toString("hex")`

Comment: @Bravo Thanks. But I want to get the same value as base64 as a result of encryption with crypto-js. (like crypto results) How can I get the base64 value in Crypto-js?

Comment: then look into the crypto-js library documentation to see if there is a way to get base64 ... otherwise `Buffer.from(yourHexString, 'hex').toString('base64')`

Comment: @Bravo Thanks!! resolved.     cipherText.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)